# Group By and Count the total number of same status value

Tags: c#, sql, group-by, count, linq-to-sql

I have 2 tables, Order and Store. And here are some of the fields from the table I need.

Order table

```
  OrderId StoreId SystemOrderStatus
     1       1        Received
     2       1        Sent
     3       2        Complete
     4       2        Received
```

How can I achieve to have this output:

```
StoreId ReceivedStatusCount SentStatusCount CompleteStatusCount
     1            1                1                0
     2            1                0                1
```

Thank you.

Comment: Is this a SQL or a LINQ question?

Comment: This is for LINQ query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `case when`, as blow:

```
select
    StoreId,
    sum(case when SystemOrderStatus='Received' then 1 else 0 end) as ReceivedStatusCount,
    sum(case when SystemOrderStatus='Sent' then 1 else 0 end) as SentStatusCount,
    sum(case when SystemOrderStatus='Complete' then 1 else 0 end) as CompleteStatusCount
from
    "Order"
group by
    StoreId
order by
    StoreId
```

Comment: `This is for LINQ query`